# How to generate a 'single' sourcemap for entire project using babel 6?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, source-maps

Is it possible to generate a **single** sourcemap for an entire project using babel?
Because each sourcemap foe each file generates an ugly project structure.

Comment: What about having a map file for each output file is ugly? Why is the output format something that matters?

Comment: I just want to know it its possible and it matters since if i have a sourcemap for an entire project instead of having each file having its own sourcemap which clutters the project.Also the only utility of a sourcemap is to map the o/p code with the source code and one file alone for the entireproject would do its job is'nt it?

Answer (score 0):

The sourcemap format is explicitly per-file that the JS environment loads. It maps a source line/column location to a new filename and line/column number, but it is strictly one executed file to many original files. If you wanted to have a single sourcemap file with all the mappings for potentially many different output files generated from many input files, that would require a many-to-many relationship.

One option you might consider, if clutter during local development is your core concern, would be to use inline sourcemaps rather than separate files. Most sourcemap utilities support sourcemaps being appended to the JS file they are associated with as a comment containing a data URL.

Separate sourcemap files would still ideally be used if you have sourcemaps enabled in production however.